# How do I increase the size of a buffered image to the left and upwards?

Tags: java, image

I need to know how to increase the size of my buffered image to the left and up, not just the right and down.

```
bI = new BufferedImage(yMax*size*5, xMax*size*5, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Answer (score 1):

The "direction" of expansion would only matter if you already had data contained in the buffer. If you have a buffered image already, then want to make a larger one, you'll need to copy the data into the new larger buffer. When you copy the data into the new buffer you simply place the existing data at the bottom right corner. Like this:

[image]

Where `x,y` are the width,height of the old buffer and `x2,y2` are the width,height of the new buffer.

So copying the data in I would get the old buffered data with [getRGB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) then place that in the new buffer with [setRGB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).